# In Spark, What is the reason of getting EOF exception, Seek past end of file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, eof, databricks

I am reading some data (8 GB) data from multiple files, filter the data doing some null check and performing some upliftings (operations) on columns like cleaning column value for this I have 6 to 7 functions (custom functionality, cannot use spark functions) that are registered as UDFs. Then I write the final result to tables and CSV files, now on 'dataframe.write.saveAsTable()' and on writing 'CSV' I get EOF exception Seek past end of file. This exception does not occur everytime, like if I run 20 times it may occur once. I am unable to find its reason and cause because it is not reproduce-able, (Getting this in both in scala and pyspark), will appreciate any help or hint. Looking forward. Thanks

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-4146672194126555> in <module>()
    331 saveMergedLogs(
    332  dataframeLogs
    333 );

<command-3860558353011740> in saveMergedLogs(dataframeLogs)
     45   # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     46   spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.UsageLogs");
---> 47   dataframeLogs.write.saveAsTable("dbo.UsageLogs")

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in saveAsTable(self, name, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    773         if format is not None:
    774             self.format(format)
--> 775         self._jwrite.saveAsTable(name)
    776 
    777     @since(1.4)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3615.saveAsTable.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeAndRead(DataSource.scala:553)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.saveDataIntoTable(createDataSourceTables.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:690)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:690)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:690)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.createTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:487)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:466)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:414)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 9 in stage 58.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 9.3 in stage 58.0 (TID 8630, 10.139.64.7, executor 0): java.io.EOFException: Cannot seek past end of file
    at com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLFileInputStream.seek(ADLFileInputStream.java:262)
    at com.databricks.adl.AdlFsInputStream.seek(AdlFsInputStream.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.seek(FSDataInputStream.java:62)
    at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FSInputStreamWithMetrics.seek(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.seek(FSDataInputStream.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.<init>(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.<init>(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.TextInputCSVDataSource$.readFile(CSVDataSource.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:338)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage443.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:622)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1432)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:503)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2100)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2088)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2087)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2087)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1076)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1076)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1076)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2319)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2267)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2255)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:873)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Cannot seek past end of file
    at com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLFileInputStream.seek(ADLFileInputStream.java:262)
    at com.databricks.adl.AdlFsInputStream.seek(AdlFsInputStream.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.seek(FSDataInputStream.java:62)
    at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FSInputStreamWithMetrics.seek(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.seek(FSDataInputStream.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.<init>(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.<init>(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.TextInputCSVDataSource$.readFile(CSVDataSource.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:338)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage443.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:622)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1432)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:503)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: It looks that might have some relation to [this](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/107/how-do-i-fix-the-following-error-with-saveastable.html) one

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis glad anyone replied to this. The link you gave is specific to dataframe.saveAsTable(), but I also face same issue If I write dataframe to a CSV file. And it is not reproduce-able because it does not occur every time but occurs 2 to 3 times in 15 runs. dont know why.

Comment: Any update on this one @Bilal?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis, no update till now. but I am looking to change my application architecture. So I have alot of transformations you can say 70+ and then at end I have two actions (inserting into CSV file and saveAsTable()). So what is happening is when saveAsTable() cmd runs and it runs all the tranformations in the DAG from the start and saves result in CSV file there if I see that how many data is read from external filesystem then the data read from the CSV files is 3.7 + 3.7 = 7.4 GB, which is correct, next

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis , next step is I take only one join and save data in CSV file. And here the data read from external file system moves from 7.4 to 27 GB. I think that It moves all the steps back to the reading step and read all the data again. And this can cause seek past end of file. What you think?

Comment: Hello @Bilal did you manage to solve this? If not can you try to persist after big joins or repartition if you have any. Also what environment are you running your job?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis, again thanks for replying and taking interest in my issue. Now when I have used caching. The occurance of this exception is reduced from 2 - 3 times in 15 To 1 time in 40 runs. But Still I cannot put this buggy code on production. I am coding in databricks notebooks in pyspark. Databricks runtime is 5.2, apache spark 2.4.0, having a cluster of 5 workers and 1 driver, each having 4 cores. Also want to know should use caching or persistance?

Comment: I would start with persistance but it depends on your cluster if you have sufficient memory or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I worked a lot on it, but there is no solution for it. The way I managed was I specified a retry in ADF databricks activity. So when ever this issue occurs it can rerun the notebook in databricks and it passes. Still this is not a perfect solution but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I met same issue when reading data from multiple files. The files have same columns but the order of the columns are not exactly the same. Since in pandas we can set sort=True when append DataFrame so that same columns in different position won't get confused, I suspected it is the order of the columns that cause the issue. I'm not 100% sure but it worked after I re-write the files with same order of columns.